# Is there a way to send logs to a remote host in real time?

Tags: linux, windows, logging

I've been experimenting with high-interaction honeypots lately. Unfortunately if an adversary achieves root access they could easily wipe the logfiles on a system, defeating one of the purposes of a high-interaction honeypot which is to observe what an adversary does.

Is there a way to send log entries as they happen in real time to a remote location? Linux and Windows are the focus here, so I guess it is a two-part question; how can this be done on both Linux and Windows?

Comment: In linux, certianly, using rsyslogd. Be sure to look into it from the perspective of 'Reliable Logging Infrastructure' as your usecase relies on the highest levels of reliability possible.

Comment: also logstash can be a part of a log server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, logging can be done in real time. This is pretty much “baked in” to the syslog protocol. he summary is -

Allow port 514 udp through firewall

In syslog.conf on client add:

```
*.* syslog.log.server.name
```

On server add

```
ip.of.client
    *.* /File/to/log.to
```

See https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/7.3-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/network-syslogd.html for more info.